# Python: Why does it keep saying invalid syntax?

Tags: python

I wrote this program in order to be able to find the number of A/U and C/G pairs from the users input. When I run it, it keeps saying "Invalid Syntax" while highlighting the first "else:" after the while loop in red. Anyone know what I need to change to fix it?

```
def main():

    first = input("Please enter the RNA sequence for which you wish to find the number of pairs. \nFirst line:")
    second = input("Second String:")

    a1base = first.count('A')
    u1base = first.count('U')
    c1base = first.count('C')
    g1base = first.count('G')
    a2base = second.count('A')
    u2base = second.count('U')
    c2base = second.count('C')
    g2base = second.count('G')

    while (a1base >= 1) and (u1base >= 1) or (a2base >= 1) and (u2base >= 1):
        abases = (a1base+ a2base)
        ubases = (u1base + u2base)
        firstset = min(abases, ubases)
        print("You have", firstset,"A/U bases.")
        else:
            print("You have zero A/U bases.")

    while (c1base >= 1) and (g1base >= 1) or (c2base >= 1) and (g2base >= 1):
        cbases = (c1base + c2base)
        gbases = (g1base + g2base)
        secondset = min(cbases, gbases)
        print("You have", secondset,"C/G bases.")
        else:
            print("You have zero C/G bases.")



main()
```

Comment: `Why does it keep saying invalid syntax?` => Usually because your syntax is invalid. In your case, your else indentation does not match any if, for or while.

Comment: As a side note, this is not a "coding-style" question. Coding style is about choosing between different legitimate ways to write or lay out equivalent, valid code, not about writing valid code in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You have an `else:` that isn't attached to any `if`, `for`, `while`, or `try` statement, which is illegal.

If you meant for the `else` to be attached to the `while`, the solution is simple: Change the indentation to attach it:

```
while (a1base >= 1) and (u1base >= 1) or (a2base >= 1) and (u2base >= 1):
    abases = (a1base+ a2base)
    ubases = (u1base + u2base)
    firstset = min(abases, ubases)
    print("You have", firstset,"A/U bases.")
else:
    print("You have zero A/U bases.")
```

See [`break` and `continue` Statements, and `else` Clauses on Loops](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) in the tutorial (and [Compound statements](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements) in the language reference for full details).

Comment: But the `else` block will always be called in this case. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @OlehPrypin Your badly indented `else` makes even less sense.

Comment: @OlehPrypin: True, but trying to guess what the OP was actually trying to do is a mug's game. Maybe he wanted to break after the first `print`, in which case he needs to add a `break`. Or maybe he wanted to keep track of whether any `print`s had occurred and only do the `else` if none did, in which case he's misusing `else`. Or maybe he wanted something completely different. I have no idea—but in any case, he first has to get the code compiling before he can figure out what to do next.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I don't think OlehPrypin is the OP here. Except in the sense that his initials are "OP". :)

Comment: Sorry both of you. As OP's loops don't have an exit condition and the variables in the initial condition are never altered, I guess the `while`s should be `if`s. But this is just consulting my crystal ball.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: That's yet another possibility I didn't think of that might make sense. My crystal ball just keeps saying "Reply hazy, try again."

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` needs to be indented at the same level as your `while`, which doesn't really make sense in this case because there's no `break` in your loop, or you need to add an `if` on some line before it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two obvious things:

1. Everything after `def main():` should be indented;
2. `Else` should be at the same level of indentation as `while`. It is not a child, but a sibling of `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained the error.

Try changing you `while` loops to this:

```
abases = (a1base+ a2base)
ubases = (u1base + u2base)
firstset = min(abases, ubases)
print("You have", firstset if firstset else 'zero',"A/U bases.")

cbases = (c1base + c2base)
gbases = (g1base + g2base)
secondset = min(cbases, gbases)
print("You have", secondset if secondset else 'zero',"C/G bases.")
```

Without any `while` or `else:`.

Also the following snippet should do the same thing:

```
first = input("Please enter the RNA sequence for which you wish to find the number of pairs. \nFirst line:")
second = input("Second String:")
bases = {k: (first + second).count(k) for k in 'AUCG'}
print('You have', min(bases['A'], bases['U']), 'A/U bases.')
print('You have', min(bases['C'], bases['G']), 'C/G bases.')
```